# Finding a Number that is less than a given number and farthest from a Point in an Array

Tags: arrays, data-structures, range, distance

Given a list of Numbers along with an index ***i*** and integer ***k*** , I wish the find the index of the number that is farthest (towards the left) from the number at index ***i*** and is less than ***k***.

```
eg
if the array is
Index :0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 .....
Array :3 4 1 5 5 4 3 7 .....
Assuming i = 7 and k = 4 , the answer would be 0
```

I have been trying to implement this using Red Black Trees, but I couldnt go any lower than O(n) . Is there any way I can reduce the complexity to O(logn) by using a different Data Structure ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, if the array is static and you want to make multiple queries for `O(log n)` each, you don't need that complicated data structures.

What you're actually asking for - "the number that is farthest (towards the left) from the number at index i and is less than k." - can be transformed to "the leftmost number before `i` that is less than `k`". Then you can see this as the following:

- find the leftmost number that is less than K - say it's at position `j`;
- if `j < i`, `j` is the answer to the question
- otherwise, there is no such number - all the entries before position `i` are larger than or equal to `k`.

To answer the first of these questions, all you need to know is: for position `i`, what is the smallest number on positions `0..i` - let's call this `min(i)`. Notice that `min` is a monotonically decreasing function of `i` - if the `min(5) = 10`, there is no way that `min(6) = 15`, since `min(6)` is the smallest number on positions `0` to `6`, and that necessarily includes the smallest number on positions `0` to `5`, which we know to be 10. (`min` is fairly trivial to construct - if we call the array `a`, then: `min(0) = a[0]`, and `min(i) = minimum(min(i - 1), a[i])` for `i > 0`.)

With this information, you can perform a binary search for the leftmost index `i` such that `min(i) < k`. Then, by the construction of `min`, we know that all numbers on positions from `0` to `i - 1` are greater than or equal to `k`. So `i` must be the answer of the question.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to build an array `mp` containing, for every 0 <= j < n, the index of the minimum of the first j elements:

```
int minPos = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    if (a[i] < a[minPos]) minPos = i;
    mp[i] = minPos;
}
```

This will take O(n) time obviously.

The elements in `mp` will refer to elements in the input array `a` that have decreasing values.  Given a query (i, k), you can now binary search `mp` for k in the range [0, i - 1], using indirection to get the actual minimum value from the minimum index:

```
int find(int i, int k) {
    int start = 0;
    int end = i - 1;

    if (a[mp[end]] >= k) return -1;    // Not found.
    if (a[mp[start]] < k) return mp[start];    // The first element is smaller.

    // We maintain the invariant that a[mp[start]] is >= k and a[mp[end]] is < k.
    while (end - start > 1) {
        int mid = (start + end) / 2;
        if (a[mp[mid]] < k) {
            end = mid;
        } else {
            start = mid;
        }
    }

    return mp[end];
}
```